# Invalid Read of size 1 on running Valgrind

Tags: c, gdb, valgrind

```
The following is the error that I got after running Valrind    
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./out



  ==12140== Invalid read of size 1
    ==12140==    at 0x4C2DF84: strncat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    ==12140==    by 0x40100D: createSortedRuns (final.c:178)
    ==12140==    by 0x401297: main (final.c:249)
    ==12140==  Address 0x51fd549 is 0 bytes after a block of size 9 alloc'd
    ==12140==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    ==12140==    by 0x400EFD: createSortedRuns (final.c:150)
    ==12140==    by 0x401297: main (final.c:249)
    ==12140==
```

The other error that I am getting is:

```
==12140== Invalid write of size 1
==12140==    at 0x4C2DFD0: strncat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12140==    by 0x40100D: createSortedRuns (final.c:178)
==12140==    by 0x401297: main (final.c:249)
==12140==  Address 0x51fd54d is 4 bytes after a block of size 9 alloc'd
==12140==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12140==    by 0x400EFD: createSortedRuns (final.c:150)
==12140==    by 0x401297: main (final.c:249)
==12140== 
==12140== 
==12140== 250 errors in context 7 of 13:
```

The other error that I am getting is:

```
==12140== Invalid read of size 1
==12140==    at 0x4C2DF84: strncat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12140==    by 0x40100D: createSortedRuns (final.c:178)
==12140==    by 0x401297: main (final.c:249)
==12140==  Address 0x51fd549 is 0 bytes after a block of size 9 alloc'd
==12140==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12140==    by 0x400EFD: createSortedRuns (final.c:150)
==12140==    by 0x401297: main (final.c:249)
==12140==
```

The following is the snippet of the program:

```
  void createSortedRuns(int start, int end, char file[]){

        FILE *givenFile = NULL;
        givenFile=fopen(file,"r+b");
        rewind(givenFile);
        int i=0;
        /*printf("File:%s\n",file);
        printf("File Length:%zu\n",strlen(file));*/
        char *temp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(file));



        for(i=start; i<end; i++){
            fseek(givenFile,0,SEEK_CUR);
            fread(&inputBuffer[act_inputBufferSize],sizeof(int),1,givenFile);
            act_inputBufferSize++;

            if((act_inputBufferSize==max_inputBufferSize) ||(i==(end-1))){

                //sort
                qsort(inputBuffer,act_inputBufferSize,sizeof(int),compare);

                // write to file

                strncpy(temp,file,strlen(file));


                //int k=0;
                char counter[4]={0};
                /*for(k=0;k<4;k++){
                    counter[k]=0;
                }*/


                snprintf(counter,5, ".%03d", totalSortedFiles);
                counter[strlen(counter)] = '\0';
                strncat(temp,counter,4);

                FILE *int_File = NULL;
                int_File=fopen(temp,"w+b");
                rewind(int_File);
                fwrite(&inputBuffer,sizeof(int),act_inputBufferSize,int_File);

                // register the sub_fo information
                small_fo=register_sub_fo(small_fo,totalSortedFiles,temp, 0 ,act_inputBufferSize,act_inputBufferSize);


                // increase the totalSortedFiles
                totalSortedFiles+=1;


                // Reinitialize
                            int j=0;
                            for(j=0;j<max_inputBufferSize;j++){
                                inputBuffer[j]=0;
                            }
                            act_inputBufferSize=0;

                            int len = strlen(temp);
                            temp[len-4] = '\0';
               // Garbage
                            fclose(int_File);
                            int_File = NULL;



            }
        } //for_end
        fclose(givenFile);
        givenFile=NULL;

        free(temp);
        temp=NULL;


    } // func_end
```

Valgrind is showing that the error is at line "strncat(temp,counter,4);"    Can someone please explain me the error ?

Comment: `char *temp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(file));` too small area.

Comment: May also want to use sizeof(file) versus strlen of the file as well.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY can you please explain ?

Comment: `temp` is only the length of the file name. NUL character to not be attached, can not even be coupled to other strings.

Comment: `snprintf(counter,5, ".%03d", totalSortedFiles);` but `char counter[4]={0};`

Answer (score 2):

`strncpy` function does not zero-terminate the target buffer if the size limit was reached during copying. You are using `strncpy` in your code and it definitely reaches the size limit

```
strncpy(temp,file,strlen(file));
```

This means that at this point `temp` is not zero-terminated. `temp` is not a string after this `strncpy` call.

After that you do

```
strncat(temp,counter,4);
```

But `strncat` requires its first operand to be a string. In your case it is not a string. The behavior is undefined.

As it has been stated many times, `strncpy` is not a limited-length string copying function. Using it as such is error prone and lame. Even if it can be made to "work", it is still not the right tool for the job.

In addition to that, the buffer you allocated for `temp` cannot accommodate any more characters in addition to what is already there after that `strncpy`. The buffer is allocated as exactly `strlen(file)` characters long.

Also, this statement does not seem to make any sense at ll

```
counter[strlen(counter)] = '\0';
```

In order for `strlen` to work, your `counter` must already be properly zero-terminated. So, what you are doing is re-terminating the `counter` string at the exact location at which it is already terminated. What is the point of that?

You don't need to do that. `snprintf` already produced a zero-terminated string.

However, your `snprintf` invocation is problematic by itself.

```
char counter[4]={0};
snprintf(counter,5, ".%03d", totalSortedFiles);
```

Your `counter` array is declared with size 4. By passing 5 as the buffer size to `snprintf` you are lying to `snprintf`. In general case `snprintf` will go out of bounds. The behavior is undefined.

The format you used in `snprintf` suggests that you actually need a buffer of size 5.

Comment: I understood that the temp buffer allocated is not enough to accommodate the counter array. Can you please suggest all the changes that needs to be made in the above program. Also I did not understand the working of strncat, strncpy and snprintf. Can you please suggest some good documents or links that I can refer to ?